# Why is an experimental basis used to solve the scattering state problem of the finite well when they do not represent a physical particle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, boundary-conditions

The first time I was doing the finite square well problem in QM, there was a dissection of the problem into bound and scattering states. For the bound states, the appropriate boundary conditions were applied and the solution was obtained.

Coming to the scattering states, I saw this experimental basis of probability current being used. It said that if we throw in a ***particle*** from the left, the waves get transmitted, reflected, and so on to eliminate the constant which represented a wave traveling left in the left-most region.

But since scattering states do not point to physical particles, why is such an intuitively experimental basis (physical) being used to eliminate constants in the problem?

Please help. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a *scattering problem* as opposed to the *eigenstates problem*. In principle these must be treated in different chapters, since they point out to different settings and dufferent mathematical developments. So you are right to pose the question.

What is hidden under the carpet is that for the bound states in a square well one cannot form a scattering problem (although this is not necessarily the case for other potentials with bound states). Likewise, treating continuous spectrum as an eigenstate problem is rather cumbersome and poses difficulties with normalization (although it is possible). So some shortcuts were done in order to focus on the properties of the square well potential.